# Problema al pasar parámetros mediante url django

Tags: django, django-urls, django-views

Estoy creando un sistema que me active un usuario recién creado, para ello el usuario ingresa en una URL como esta:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/activate/**poAEwRNg>IFLKCX**/**email@gmail.com**/
```

mi fichero **urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from home.views import homePageView, activateUser

urlpatterns = [
    path('',homePageView.as_view(),name='home'),
    path('activate/<string:code>/<string:email>/$', activateUser.activate, name='activate')
]
```

mi fichero **views.py**

```
# home/views.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponse
from home.forms import *
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from home.models import Usuario
import bcrypt
import hashlib
import sha3
from random import choice

class activateUser():
    def activate(self, code, email):
        print(code,email)
        return HttpResponse('Activating user: '+code+' email: '+email)
```

la consola de django me da este error:

> "URL route '%s' uses invalid converter %s." % (original_route, e)
>    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: URL route 'activate///$' uses invalid converter
>   'string'.

¿Cómo puedo capturar los parámetros en negrita de la url entonces?

*Utilizo Django 2.0

El código tiene un tamaño de 15 elementos siempre*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he encontrado la solución, modificando el fichero **urls.py** talq ue así:

```
#home/urls.py
from django.urls import path, re_path
from home.views import homePageView, activateUser

urlpatterns = [
    path('',homePageView.as_view(),name='home'),
    re_path('activate/([a-zA-Z0-9]{15})/([\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$', activateUser.activate, name='activate')
]
```